# Sorting dates within objects using dplyr in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, plyr

I have the following data:

```
Number     Year
 1       2001-01-01
 1       2001-02-01
 1       2002-03-01
 1       2001-03-01
 1       1999-07-01
 2       2001-01-01
 2       2001-02-01
 2       2002-03-01
 2       2001-03-01
 2       1999-07-01
 3       2001-01-01
 3       2001-02-01
 3       2002-03-01
 3       2001-03-01
 3       1999-07-01
```

Now I need to sort the dates within each number. I want my final output to look like this.

```
Number     Year
 1       1999-07-01
 1       2001-01-01
 1       2001-02-01
 1       2001-03-01
 1       2002-03-01
 2       1999-07-01
 2       2001-01-01
 2       2001-02-01
 2       2001-03-01
 2       2002-03-01
 3       1999-07-01
 3       2001-01-01
 3       2001-02-01
 3       2001-03-01
 3       2002-03-01
```

This is a simplified form of my data. I tried using dplyr.

This is my code:

```
df <- ddply(df, by = 'Number', function(datesort){
  datesort[order(datesort$date),]

  })
```

I get the error:

> Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") :    no applicable method for
>   'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Number) %>% arrange(Year) `

Comment: I tried that. It says cannot find function "%>%"

Comment: Make sure you have latest dplyr installed and loaded? `library(dplyr)`

Comment: I reloaded it. But in my output, the numbers are not together anymore. The Years are all sorted in ascending.

Comment: Ok, I used arrange as andrew_reece suggested and I got it!! Thank you!

Comment: Both `plyr` and `dplyr` load a function called `arrange`. However, the `plyr` version is not "aware" of `dplyr` grouping information. Try `df %>% group_by(Number) %>% dplyr::arrange(Year)` to ensure that the right version is called. Be aware that `dplyr` is meant to replace `plyr`, and `plyr` should no longer be used.

Comment: See below answer, my above comment is slightly wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess for what you were going for is a `plyr` solution, with `ddply`, and using `Year` instead of `date`:

```
require(plyr)

ddply(df, "Number", function(datesort) datesort[order(datesort$Year),])
```

But given that this post is tagged `dplyr`, here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% arrange(Number, Year)
```

Both solutions output:

```
   Number Year      
    <int> <date>    
 1      1 1999-07-01
 2      1 2001-01-01
 3      1 2001-02-01
 4      1 2001-03-01
 5      1 2002-03-01
 6      2 1999-07-01
 7      2 2001-01-01
 8      2 2001-02-01
 9      2 2001-03-01
10      2 2002-03-01
11      3 1999-07-01
12      3 2001-01-01
13      3 2001-02-01
14      3 2001-03-01
15      3 2002-03-01
```

Data:

```
zz <-"Number     Year
 1       2001-01-01
 1       2001-02-01
 1       2002-03-01
 1       2001-03-01
 1       1999-07-01
 2       2001-01-01
 2       2001-02-01
 2       2002-03-01
 2       2001-03-01
 2       1999-07-01
 3       2001-01-01
 3       2001-02-01
 3       2002-03-01
 3       2001-03-01
 3       1999-07-01"

df <- read.table(text=zz, header=TRUE)
```

Comment: `df %>% arrange(Number, Year)` is sufficient.